# Unable to start service MSSQLSERVER on server (mscorlib)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I tried to restart a remote SQL server (2012 full) and I got this error:

> Unable to start service MSSQLSERVER on server (mscorlib)

[image: screenshot]

Every time I try I get this message. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the service got setup wrong.
Try The following:

- Run **services.msc**
- Find the **MSSQLSERVER** Service.
- Right click and open **properties**
- Check what service account it is running under (usually NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM, NTAUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE or NTAUTHORITY\NETWORK SERIVICE unless you have it running under a different user account for security purposes).

Also, they might have moved things around in 2012 I'm still on 2008 R2

Comment: MSSQLSERVER not exist in my services.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi, maybe look for "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message for days. I went to my domain controller and changed the password of the sql server agent and updated the password in the configuration manager. And, it connected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Services and right click on sql server agent. select properties and update password/ confirm password if you not using local system account. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

changing password and restarting service works for me

Comment: You are answering a 7 year old question. Not that there is anything wrong with it, just to let you know.